# Set the values of a property automatically based on another property and cache them for later use

Tags: python, properties

I have defined a class that returns some of the parameters as follows

```
class PHYParams:

    def __init__(self, bandwidth):
        #Static
        self.n_symbols = 7
        self.nrb_sc = 12

        # Properties        
        self.bw = bandwidth        

    @property
    def bw(self):
        return self._bw

    @bw.setter
    def bw(self, value):
        if value in [10, 20]:
            self._bw = value
        else:
            print('Invalid Bandwidth value. Taking default of 10 MHz')
            self._bw = 10

    @property
    def NSLRB(self):
        return self.bw * 5

    @property
    def NFFT(self):
        return int(self.bw * 102.4)
```

The properties `NSLRB` and `NFFT` would be used heavily later. However, as per this implementation, everytime I call one of these functions, it invokes the get attribute which involves re-calculation. I am trying to avoid trying to put them in the `__init__` since it will not refresh its value if I change the `bw` property at a later time. Is there a way of caching them so that instead of calculating everytime, they would only be calculated when the `bw` property is changed and stores them as an attribute so that I can just call them like a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set those two attributes in the `bw` setter, don't make them `property` objects:

```
class PHYParams:
    def __init__(self, bandwidth):
        #Static
        self.n_symbols = 7
        self.nrb_sc = 12

        # Properties        
        self.bw = bandwidth        

    @property
    def bw(self):
        return self._bw

    @bw.setter
    def bw(self, value):
        if value in [10, 20]:
            self._bw = value
        else:
            print('Invalid Bandwidth value. Taking default of 10 MHz')
            self._bw = 10

        self.NSLRB = self._bw * 5
        self.NFFT = int(self._bw * 102.4)
```

There is no requirement that properties only touch 'their own' attribute state.

As an aside: If someone sets a wrong bandwith value, don't use `print()` to communicate this. Either use just override and set the bandwidth to 10 and output a [warning with `warnings.warn()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html), or raise an exception so the developer passing in the wrong value can correct their code:

```
@bw.setter
def bw(self, value):
    if value not in {10, 20}:
        value = 10
        warning.warn('Invalid Bandwidth value. Taking default of 10 MHz', RuntimeWarning)
    self._bw = value
    self.NSLRB = self._bw * 5
    self.NFFT = int(self._bw * 102.4)
```

or

```
@bw.setter
def bw(self, value):
    if value not in {10, 20}:
        raise ValueError('Invalid Bandwidth value, only 10 or 20 allowed', value)
    self._bw = value
    self.NSLRB = self._bw * 5
    self.NFFT = int(self._bw * 102.4)
```

Comment: OMG! How did I miss that? Thanks a ton

Comment: Thanks for the pointer regarding warnings. I had thought of using the `raise ValueError` but the warning seems to be a better fit